# Class 'List<Student>' has no instance getter 'values'. Receiver: Instance(length:11) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: values

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

This is my code to get data from sqflite in flutter but while doing that I get the following error :

`Class 'List<Student>' has no instance getter 'values'. Receiver: Instance(length:11) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: values`

```
DBHelper dbHelper;
Future<List<Student>> students;

 FutureBuilder(
                future:students,

                builder: (  context,   snapshot) {

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();
                    for (var value in snapshot.data.values){
                      lst.add(value);
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child:
                        //Text('{$snapshot.data.values.toList()[0]["name"]}')

                      InfoCard(

                        title:snapshot.data.values.toList()[0]["name"] ,//snapshot.data.documents[0].toString(),// snapshot.data.values.toList()[0]["name"],
                        iconColor: Color(0xFFFF8C00),
                        effectedNum: '1062',
                        press: () {},
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1):

That's cause `snapshot.data` is a List in itself, so ya don't need the `.values.toList()` attribute. So, just remove that part.

```
DBHelper dbHelper;
Future<List<Student>> students;

 FutureBuilder(
                future:students,

                builder: (  context,   snapshot) {

                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                 List<Student> lst = new List<Student>();
                    for (var value in snapshot.data){
                      lst.add(value);
                    }
                    return Center(
                      child:
                        //Text('{$snapshot.data[0]["name"]}')

                      InfoCard(

                        title:snapshot.data[0]["name"] as String, //snapshot.data.documents[0].toString(),// snapshot.data.values.toList()[0]["name"],
                        iconColor: Color(0xFFFF8C00),
                        effectedNum: '1062',
                        press: () {},
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: I try this but still appear same error please help me

Comment: Show me the error that you're getting. Make an edit to your original post

Comment: This is error:Class 'List<Student>' has no instance getter 'values'. Receiver: Instance(length:11) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: values

Comment: There were 3 places where you used `snapshot.data.values`. Change it in all those places.